# File not found: Beautiful Soup

Tags: ubuntu, files, python

I am trying to run a program that I downloaded in Ubuntu latest version, but I continue getting an error everytime I try to run the program. It says:

```
File Not Found: BeautifulSoup
```

So in order to attempt to fix this, I've downloaded the bs4 beautiful soup  package through the command line. I've tried running `python`, and then importing it by doing, `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

I have tried many different variations of this and downloading and redownloading it. I've tried running the `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` directly from the terminal, but that did not work and returned an error.

Does anyone know anyway to fix this issue or what I need to do?

Comment: What program were you trying to run that gave you this error?

Comment: Have you used `pip` to install beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the package `python-beautifulsoup` in a Ubuntu system running the command below as root:

```
apt-get install python-beautifulsoup
```

This will install the package under `/usr/share/pyshared` and importing it should work.

Comment: i love you so much right now

Comment: i used "easy_install" to do it and i got easy install, no idea why that didnt work

Comment: Either pip or easy_install should also work but using the ubuntu package will solve the problem